# How to check gtk version in Vala?

Tags: gtk3, vala

I am developing some `Gtk` based application using Vala. In my application I want to add some custom styles.

I want to retain my styles for both Gtk 3.20- and Gtk 3.20+ versions. As we are aware, Gtk3 has changed widget classes beginning from Gtk 3.20.

So, how can I check the gtk version and apply custom style accordingly? I know that, I can apply both styles together. But don't want to overload the app with unnecessary styles.

I'm looking for something like this

```
string style = null;
If (GTK_VERSION >= 3.20) {
    style = "window {border : none}";
} else {
    style = "GtkWindow {border : none}";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Gtk.get_major_versoin()` and `Gtk.get_minor_version()` for getting major and minor versions respectively.

```
string style = null;
if (((Gtk.get_major_version() * 100) + (Gtk.get_minor_version())) >= 320)
  style = "window {border : none}";
} else {
  style = "GtkWindow {border : none}";
}
```

Reference:

- [Gtk.get_major_version()](https://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.get_major_version.html)
- [Gtk.get_minor_version()](https://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.get_minor_version.html)